# Screen Detection In Android

Tags: android

I would need your help to share me your code.
 - How to detect Width and Height of a screen?
 - How to divide screen into 2 parts (full screen mode , portrait), upside (70% of screen) and downside(30% of screen)?

many thank for your help.
Dorang

Comment: Use weight in ur xml. It handles and no need to do programmatically

Comment: Note that generally you would not need this, as there are better ways to adapt your app to different devices. It can be useful in some very special cases, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public int screenWidth;   public int screenHeight;



public void getScreenSize() {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);        screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;         screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    }
```